# Determine if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, given that it is continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Define $f(x,y)= \frac{x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}$ if $(x,y)≠(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Determine if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Using limits and converting to polar coordinates, I determined that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

I also got that the partial derivatives exist and are constant functions both equal to $0$. But how do I determine from this if $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$, step by step if possible?

Comment: I would point to [this generally useful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1405795/173410).

Comment: There's also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902768/fx-yt-fracxy2x2y2-not-differentiable-in-0-0t) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409924/proving-something-is-not-differentiable) and [more](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x%2Cy)%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2y%7D%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%7D%24%2C%20differentiable&p=1).